# How to detect if the script is trying to add the two same IDs?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a logger for IDs and names, but I can't seem to detect if the script is trying to add the two same IDs.

I've tried `id.includes(user._id)`, but it always passed the `if` test. Here's the code:

```
let id = [];
MPP.client.on('participant added', user => {
    if (id.includes(user._id))
        return console.log(
            `%c - joined, seen ${user._id}, n: ${user.name}`,
            'color: red;'
        );
    id.push({ id: user._id, n: user.name, action: 'joined' });
    console.log(
        `%c + joined, added ${user._id} to list, n: ${user.name}`,
        'color: lime;'
    );
});
MPP.client.on('participant removed', user => {
    if (id.includes(user._id))
        return console.log(
            `%c - left, seen ${user._id}, n: ${user.name}`,
            'color: red;'
        );
    id.push({ id: user._id, n: user.name, action: 'left' });
    console.log(
        `%c + left, added ${user._id} to list, n: ${user.name}`,
        'color: lime;'
    );
});
```

Comment: You have an array of objects but you check if the array includes a string

Comment: I know but I need to modify the if check so it can check for objects

Comment: `includes` is useful only if you have the full value you want to search for. Use a function like [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to search with a predicate.

Comment: Does `some` work on object arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search your `id` array with `find` this will give you the current object which you can match your `user._id` against.

```js
if (id.find(participant => participant.id === user._id))
  return ...
```